# Database sqllite how to calculate total amount in android?

Tags: android

I am created one table For example Product name Product price product quantity  Product Id. I want to pass id argument Product Id and get all value Product price .How to calculate all Product price in total amount.Give me some query. and also if i have to change product quantity   means multiply to Product price amount automatically in text view .I have used custom list view i have insert all data don't  know this scenario .

For Example

Screen UI

Productname Productprice Productquantity productid

Meals       345          Edittext 3      3454

Egg         32               4           2323

Briyani     223              2           2365

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass id argument Product Id and get all value Product price
>   .How to calculate all Product price in total amount.

You need to use [SUM()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) function for calculating prices and that all what you need:

```
String query = "select SUM(price) from Product where product_id = ?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"someValue"});
double sum;
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   sum = c.getDouble(0);
}
```

> How to calculate all Product price in total amount.

```
String query = "select SUM(price) from Product";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
double total;
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
   total = c.getDouble(0);
}
```

Comment: thank u very much but i want modify quantity means automatically amount will be change how to do?

Comment: mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM "+(columnproductprice) + "FROM " + TABLErestaurant + " WHERE columnproductid=?", new String[] { selArgs });

Comment: near restaurant syntax error occur.This raw Query i think wrong can you give me solution.

Comment: If i have put in sum = c.getDouble(0); means i got last value only

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify Your sum = c.getDouble(c.getColumnCount());

best luck